# loopback hasMany through gives empty array

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

i have the following defined models:

**Academy**

```
{
  "name": "academy",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "updated": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "academy_version_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "versions": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "academy_version",
      "foreignKey": "academy_id",
      "through": "academy_has_versions"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**academy_version**

```
        {
      "name": "academy_version",
      "base": "PersistedModel",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "number",
          "required": true
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "created": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "updated": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {
        "academies": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "academy",
          "foreignKey": "academy_version_id",
          "through": "academy_has_versions"
        }
      },
      "acls": [],
      "methods": {}
    }
```

**academy_has_versions**

```
{
  "name": "academy_has_versions",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "academy_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "academy_version_id": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "academy": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "academy",
      "foreignKey": "academy_id"
    },
    "academy_version": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "academy_version",
      "foreignKey": "academy_version_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Now as you can see my `academy` model has a `hasMany` through `academy_has_versions`

When i attempt to request this i get the following result:

[image]

As you can see i get an empty array (versions)

This is incorrect because my database look like this:

**academy_has_versions**

[image]

**academy_version**

[image]

So can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the error but I suggest you try this:

1. Remove the "id" property from all models since idInjection is set to true.
2. Remove the properties corresponding to foreign keys.
3. Remove the academy_version_id property from the academy model since doesn't has sense in the relation.

**Academy**

```
{
  "name": "academy",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "updated": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "versions": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "academy_version",
      "foreignKey": "academy_id",
      "through": "academy_has_versions"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**academy_version**

```
{
      "name": "academy_version",
      "base": "PersistedModel",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "created": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "updated": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {
        "academies": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "academy",
          "foreignKey": "academy_version_id",
          "through": "academy_has_versions"
        }
      },
      "acls": [],
      "methods": {}
    }
```

**academy_has_versions**

```
{
  "name": "academy_has_versions",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "academy": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "academy",
      "foreignKey": "academy_id"
    },
    "academy_version": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "academy_version",
      "foreignKey": "academy_version_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```